# Aligning the vdots with terms in a system of equations

Tags: ms-word

How do you align the \vdots in a 'general form of a system of equations with its corresponding terms, like the one available in wikipedia (as shown in the image below) using **MS Word equation editor**? Do I have to adjust\align it manually or is there an alternative way in which the \vdots aligns automatically with the terms?

Here's the image from wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to line up vertical dots in Equation editor in Word like this:

[image: As in Word]

You *can* do this - use the matrix template tool (highlighted):

[image: matrix template]

and enter a matrix which will fit your data. In my case I used a matrix of 9 columns and 4 rows - I've deliberately left in the placeholders to illustrate what I did:

[image: editing]

You can modify the column spacing by going to the Format/Spacing menu, viz:

[image: format menu]

n.b. I'm using Word 2003 so the GUI may be different if you're using a new version, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you sir. However, Isn't that lengthy? I mean, too much space between the characters, compared to the space if your using the syntax editor in MS Word? Sorry for being rude sir, I truly am.

Comment: Not rude at all. The column sizes can be modified in the equation editor to suit your needs.

Comment: @wespetiger — I've modified my answer to say how to modify the column spacing.

Comment: Yes, you gave me an idea on how to do it alternatively. haha. Also, I want to try using TeX editor, so I just installed mathtype. Your help is appreciated, thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: No problem. Answering your question brought back fond memories of writing my PhD thesis - thank **you**!.